# current date time to dd-mon-yyyy hh:mm:ss

Tags: javascript, html, date

In javascript I need to change the current date in the following format?I googled a lot but I didnt find the exact result.

I'm expecting the current date to format is **22-Sep-2017 13:37:02**

Thanks in Advance

Comment: https://momentjs.com/

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript) might be useful.

Comment: @phil Is possible to do it using raw javascript ?

Comment: It is but very inefficient

Comment: moment.js **is** raw javascript. Why re-invent the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var ele = document.getElementsByTagName('h3')[0];

setInterval(function(){
 var date =new moment().format('DD-MMM-YYYY hh:mm:ss');
 ele.innerHTML = date;}
 ,1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js"></script>
<h3></h3>
```

Use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/) and format your date according to your need.